# Why the value stored in 'z' is 35? Shouldn't it be 20 since in the function 'c=*b' (c is equal to the value pointed by *b)?

Tags: c, pointers

In the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void shuffle(int* a, int* b, int c) {
   int temp = *a;
   *a = *b + c;
   c = *b;
   *b = temp;
} 

int main() {
   int x = 10;
   int y = 20;
   int z = 35;
   shuffle(&x,&y,z);
   printf("x: %i\n", x);
   printf("y: %i\n", y);
   printf("z: %i\n", z);
   return 0;
}
```

The value of 'z' remains 35. Why is that so? Shouldn't the value be 20? Since:

```
c = *b;
```

Comment: It is unchanged because it is not passed as a pointer.

Comment: Z in main is different from c in shuffle. If you want to modify z, you have to pass address of z like &z.  So replace with shuffle(&x, &y, &z)   and void shuffle (int* a, int *b, int *c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a, b and c as parameters you can notice something, that `int c` is not passed as a pointer. In C the parameters can be passed two ways.

The first is reference-passed parameter, the parameter is passed as the address of the variable, any change done to the content of that address will persist even out of the function.

The second way is to pass it as a by-value parameter, in that case, you only create a copy of the content of the "passed" variable to another.

Now, `int* a` is passed as a reference (because it is a pointer), lets say a=0x12341234(address of a) and its value is 10, and one more time, `int c` (not a pointer) has 0x10101010 as an address with a value of 35. 
Then, when our function is called with a as a pointer and c as a normal integer, we can realize that inside the function the address of a stills 0x12341234, however, address of c is now 0x20202020(for example). We have created a copy of c in another place of the memory. Modifying a copied variable does not modify the original variable. This is like:

```
int original = 20;
int copy = original;//we see that copy is a COPY of original
copy = 321;//Original still being 20
```